# Optimizing Bingo Caller Method

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge

I am dong a competitive programming problem I have passed all the tests.
but my program times out. I need help optimizing my code so it can run faster.

---

> Task:
>
> - Finish method:   `BingoCaller.GetNumber()`
> - Return all numbers in the range of 1 until 75 once and in random    order
> - If there are no numbers left, return an empty string
> - The numbers are returned one by one in Bingo style:
>
>   `"I27", "N40", "B5", "B12", "I28", "O69", "B1", ...`
> - These are the ranges that you must follow:
>
>   - A number within range 1 to    15 starts with a 'B'
>   - A number within range 16 to 30 starts with an    'I'
>   - A number within range 31 to 45 starts with an 'N'
>   - A number within range 46 to 60 starts with a 'G'
>   - A number within range 61 to 75 starts with an 'O'
> - Use `System.Random` to generate your random numbers. Pass via the    constructor for testing purposes.

---

My code below

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;

       public class BingoCaller
        {

            private Random random;


            static List<int> List = new List<int>();


            public BingoCaller(Random random)
            {
                this.random = random;

            }

            public string GetNumber()
            {

            Start:

             var item = random.Next(75);


                if (List.Contains(item))
                {
                  goto Start;
                }
                else
                {
                    List.Add(item);

                    if (item >= 61)
                    {
                        return "O" + item;
                    }
                    else if (item >= 46)
                    {
                        return "G" + item;
                    }
                    else if (item >= 31)
                    {
                        return "N" + item;
                    }
                    else if (item >= 16)
                    {
                        return "I" + item;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "B" + item;
                    }

                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: I can give the test cases if you would like for this problem it is from Codewars.com

Comment: "If there are no numbers left, return an empty string".  Where in your program do you handle that requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use a `HashSet<int>` for tracking drawn numbers that has a lookup of `O(n)` and to **stop drawing new numbers if all 75 numbers has already been drawn** because calls to the `Next(..)` method are expensive and the execution time unnecessarily increases.

The `HashSet`'s `Add` method returns `true` if a value could be added so we can use it with a `while` loop until we find the next not yet drawn number.

```
private HashSet<int> _drawn = new HashSet<int>();

private int? NextNumber()
{
    var i = default(int?);
    while (_drawn.Count < 75 && !_drawn.Add((int)(i = random.Next(1, 76))));
    return i;
}

public string GetNumber()
{
    var i = NextNumber();
    if (i.HasValue)
    {
        if (i <= 15) return $"B{i}";
        if (i <= 30) return $"I{i}";
        if (i <= 45) return $"N{i}";
        if (i <= 60) return $"G{i}";
        if (i <= 75) return $"O{i}";
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

This solution passes all 19 tests and executes in about 620ms.

Remember to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` so that the `HashSet<int>` work.

---

Unfortuantelly the **C# 7** version does not work on Codewars but it looks nice too

```
public string GetNumber()
{
    switch (NextNumber())
    {            
        case int i when i <= 15: return $"B{i}";
        case int i when i <= 30: return $"I{i}";
        case int i when i <= 45: return $"N{i}";
        case int i when i <= 60: return $"G{i}";
        case int i when i <= 75: return $"O{i}";
        default: return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and with one local function we could encapsulate the `while` condition:

```
private int? NextNumber()
{
    var i = default(int?);
    bool CanDrawNext() 
    {
        return 
            _drawn.Count < 75 && 
            _drawn.Add((int)(i = random.Next(1, 76))) == false;
    }        
    while (CanDrawNext());
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I tested this.  It is faster than I thought it would be.  +1

Comment: That is completely amazing I am going to read more about Hash int's

Comment: if there are some links I could read to inform my self on that would be great thank you .

Comment: What is the argument for the `int?` in `NextNumber()?`. Why not just `int` and then return 0 if out of range?

Comment: @HenrikHansen I just find it's nicer to write `i.HasValue` then `i != -1` or `i > 0` etc. No magic numbers. Besides with a number it wouldn't work so well with the C# 7 switch that I prefer over anything else but unfortunatelly it cannot be used.

Comment: It is a elegant solution

Comment: I can not take your solution and get points for it I really have to fully understand your solution and I will make another solution of my own with the new information I know now and thank you so much @t3chb0t

Comment: please explain how the if statement works in the GetNumber() method please

Comment: I studied your code for like 2 hours and finally I get it thank you so much. I learned so much valuable information really.. I get now the genius  part of your code of how you used the Nulable<T> return type and then the HasSet<T> in the while statement so that if there was a duplicate it would pass and return null then if it was null you would just return a empty string I am so thankful it really took some time to get that logic but it was really elegant on solving this problem

Comment: @GringoJaimes exactly. You've got it. I'm glad you could learn something ;-) I didn't mean to make the logic _secret_. Next time you need to add the [tag:beginner] tag so that people know the _obvious_ parts might need more explanation. I would have explained it too if I knew you might need it but now you did some reaserch and learnt perhaps even more ;-)

Comment: I did and thank you next time I ask a question I will put the beginner tag so everybody knows I am definitely trying to learn

Comment: also I understand now the if-statement in body of  ```var i = NextNumber()```  and how ```i.HasValue``` really is a Boolean thanks to your ```int?``` syntax that was really a great code snippet superb

Answer (score 7):

It is considered bad practice to use goto-statements in modern programming because it quickly gets hard to follow the structure, so avoid that. Instead you could use a while-loop in a kind of this manner:

```
while (list.Count < 75)
{
  var number = random.Next(75);
  if (list.Contains(number))
    continue;
    ...
}
```

---

```
var item = random.Next(75);
```

This statement sets `item` to a number in the interval of \$[0, 75[\$, but you were supposed to handle the interval \$[1, 75]\$

---

instead of `if (item >= 61)` it is more readable to write `if (item > 60)`

---

It seems that `GetNumber()` is missing a stop-condition. It will run forever between `goto Start` and `Start:` when the list is full. (That may be your "time out"-problem).

---

Instead of the long list of if-statements, you could use the simple relation between the prefix's position in the word "BINGO" and the random number to extract it as:

```
string bingo = "BINGO"; // Make it a class field.
int index = ...
char prefix = bingo[index]
```

(it has something to do with 15).

---

The pattern of filling a list with found numbers tends to be slower and slower in response time as the size of the list grows because the next random number is more and more likely to be in the list. Potentially a valid number may never be found...

A better approach could be to create the list of the 75 numbers in the constructor in advance and then remove them one by one from the list when found by `random.Next()`:

```
...
var number = list[random.Next(0, list.Count)];
list.Remove(number);
...
```

This will decrease in response time and you avoid the looping.

---

**A solution could be:**

```
  public class BingoCaller
  {
    private Random random;
    List<int> list;
    string bingo = "BINGO";

    public BingoCaller(Random random)
    {
      this.random = random;
      list = Enumerable.Range(1, 75).ToList();
    }

    public string GetNumber()
    {
      if (list.Count == 0)
        return "";

      var number = list[random.Next(0, list.Count)];
      list.Remove(number);
      char prefix = bingo[(number - 1) / 15];
      return $"{prefix}{number}";
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem is still not working can I post all of my changes ?

Comment: Your solution does not work

Comment: @GringoJaimes: It is indeed working - and is in fact the fastest among the sugested solutions :-).

Comment: I keep trying your solution but really it does not work sorry

Comment: @GringoJaimes: what do you mean by "not work"?

Answer (score 2):

Searching `List` and retry until you get an unused number is not efficient
HashSet would be better but still not good as you still retry

Item needs to have a +1 when you return it

I would just shuffle once up front - exactly 74 calls to Random.Next
This is Fisher Yates shuffle - it is proven to be a correct shuffle

```
public class Bingo
{
    static List<string> bingoBalls = new List<string>(75);
    IEnumerator bingoBallsEnumerator;
    public Bingo (Random Rand)
    {
        CreateBingoBalls();
        ShuffleBingoBalls(bingoBalls, Rand);
        bingoBallsEnumerator = bingoBalls.GetEnumerator();
        //foreach (string s in bingoBalls)
        //    Debug.WriteLine(s);
        //Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
    private void CreateBingoBalls()
    {
        char[] BINGO = "BINGO".ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
        {
            string next = BINGO[(i-1) / 15] + i.ToString();
            //Debug.WriteLine(next);
            bingoBalls.Add(next);
        }
    }
    private void ShuffleBingoBalls(List<string> BingoBalls, Random Rand)
    {
        for(int i = BingoBalls.Count-1; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            int j = rand.Next(i + 1);
            if(j != i)
            {
                string temp = BingoBalls[i];
                BingoBalls[i] = BingoBalls[j];
                BingoBalls[j] = temp;
            } 
        }       
    }
    public string GetNextBingoBall()
    {
        if (bingoBallsEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return bingoBallsEnumerator.Current.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Surprised me but this is faster

```
public class Bingo2
{
    private List<int> bingoBalls = Enumerable.Range(1, 75).ToList();
    private Random rand;
    public Bingo2(Random Rand)
    {
        rand = Rand;
    }
    private int ballIndex;
    private int ballCount;
    private char[] BINGO = "BINGO".ToCharArray();
    public string GetNextBingoBall()
    {
        ballCount = bingoBalls.Count;
        if (ballCount == 0)
            return string.Empty;
        if (ballCount == 1)
        {
            ballIndex = bingoBalls[0];
            bingoBalls.Clear();
            return BINGO[(ballIndex - 1) / 15] + ballIndex.ToString();
        }
        ballIndex = bingoBalls[random.Next(ballCount)];
        bingoBalls.Remove(ballIndex);
        return BINGO[(ballIndex - 1) / 15] + ballIndex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers focus on using `Random` in the `GetNumber()` method, which isn't necessary.

We can speed this up by eliminating the random from that method entire.

What's the one, absolute truth about our desired task? **The order will never change**. We can build the order of our numbers in the constructor, and create an index field instead of all the code being in the `GetNumber()` method.

We can also make this run in \$O(n)\$ time (right now you have no big-O run-time, your method could be running infinitely).

Code:

```
class BingoCaller
{
    private int[] _numbers;
    private int _index;
    private const string _letterMap = "BINGO";

    public BingoCaller(Random rand)
    {
        _numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 75).OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToArray();
    }

    public string GetNumber()
    {
        if (_numbers.Length > _index)
        {
            var num = _numbers[_index++];
            return _letterMap[(num - 1) / 15].ToString() + num;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

My test:

```
void Main()
{
    var lastNumber = string.Empty;
    var bingoCaller = new BingoCaller(new Random(0));
    var numbers = new List<string>();

    while ((lastNumber = bingoCaller.GetNumber()) != string.Empty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Number: {lastNumber}");
        numbers.Add(lastNumber);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Unique numbers: {numbers.GroupBy(x => x).Count()}");
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Number: I16
> Number: N37
> Number: I24
> Number: I30
> Number: O65
> Number: N43
> Number: G49
> Number: O67
> Number: N31
> Number: G55
> Number: B5
> Number: O62
> Number: O70
> Number: G50
> Number: N44
> Number: B10
> Number: B11
> Number: N33
> Number: I20
> Number: G47
> Number: N39
> Number: N38
> Number: G51
> Number: B8
> Number: N32
> Number: G48
> Number: B12
> Number: B14
> Number: O72
> Number: G54
> Number: N41
> Number: I26
> Number: I29
> Number: B4
> Number: B6
> Number: G53
> Number: O61
> Number: B13
> Number: N35
> Number: O68
> Number: O73
> Number: I19
> Number: G60
> Number: I28
> Number: I25
> Number: N42
> Number: G52
> Number: O74
> Number: B1
> Number: G58
> Number: N36
> Number: B3
> Number: G46
> Number: O75
> Number: I21
> Number: B2
> Number: G57
> Number: O69
> Number: O66
> Number: I22
> Number: G59
> Number: I17
> Number: G56
> Number: O63
> Number: O64
> Number: B7
> Number: N45
> Number: I27
> Number: N40
> Number: B9
> Number: B15
> Number: N34
> Number: I23
> Number: I18
> Number: O71
> Unique numbers: 75
> ```

The 'Unique numbers' line prints 75, which means we had no duplicates.

Now I won't guarantee that this passes their tests. They might be passing a specific `Random` and expecting a specific order, but this will return a consistent order each and every time.

Comment: My original answer passed all tests but is slow and times out

Comment: your answer only passes about 4 tests

Comment: @GringoJaimes Probably because they rely on the random generator to be the part generating the values.

Comment: I am sorry can you show me an example I don't mean to be ignorant

Comment: I am studying your code and for sure it looks the best

Comment: @GringoJaimes It probably cannot be modified to fit their tests (I'm looking at that particular challenge right now) because the tests generate fake randoms that are not actually random or even a sequence, they're simply the same value constantly returned.

Comment: What can be done ?

Comment: @GringoJaimes Unfortunately, not much with this solution, unless I combine it with another which I think I'm about to try.

Comment: @GringoJaimes Will edit a working solution into the answer in just a moment.

Comment: I have learned so much already but why my solution is slow.. I am going to fix it up as much as I can how would I update it

Comment: This is nit picking but the flaw there is that a tie would default to the original order.   It is not considered a *correct* shuffle.